# Non ad hoc way for vt100 / ansi-color escapes within M-x shell

Tags: emacs, terminal, ansi-colors

I `M-x shell` to run a program that tries to produce nice color output. But I get:

```
?- true.
^[[1mtrue.^[[0m
```

This is clearly not a fault of EMACS, as it sets the environment variable TERM to dumb. It is just the program I called that ignored this information.

I am aware of `ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on` which fixes this problem in an ad hoc manner: The environment variable TERM is still dumb. That is, a program interpreting this variable accordingly would not use escapes at all.

Is there a less ad-hoc approach to this, setting the TERM or similar?

Comment: It is unclear what it is you might consider to be a non-ad-hoc solution - turning on `ansi-color-for-comint-mode` doesn't seem all that ad hoc. If the program insists on outputting colors on a TTY, what else can you do but interpret (or ignore) them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `M-x ansi-term` instead of the other shells (`M-x shell`, `M-x term` and `M-x eshell`). Ansi-term was designed to work off-the-shelf with ansi colors.  And even better, I suggest that you use [multi-term](http://www.emacswiki.org/MultiTerm) (you can read more about it [here](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/06/console-apps-in-emacs-with-multi-term.html) and [here](http://paralambda.org/2012/07/02/using-gnu-emacs-as-a-terminal-emulator/)) which essentially supports all the features of ansi-term plus the ability to easily switch between terminals and define which keyboard shortcuts are sent to the terminal and which ones are captured and interpreted by Emacs.

Answer (score 5):

If M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on does it, customizing ansi-color-for-comint-mode should be all you need.

Comment: Put it differently: Is there a reason for the default M-x term at all?

Comment: @false  - I personally use `M-x ansi-term` whenever I need a fully functional terminal in Emacs.  How is `M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode` different from `M-x ansi-term`?

Comment: @user273158: Your solution is the least ad hoc one.

Comment: @false, I have just added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, in line with the examples below:

```
(setenv "DISPLAY" ":0")

(setenv "PATH" (concat "/home/an_user/bin:"
                (getenv "PATH")))
```

You could try:

```
(setenv "TERM" ....)
```

Or is this not what you had in mind?

Comment: Yea, figured it, thought it was worth the shot. Delete?

Comment: What do you mean with "dumb" exactly?

Comment: dumb as when I say `echo $TERM` within Emacs